# Properties of $ f(x)=|x|^{1/(x-1)} $ (MCQ Contest)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, contest-math

> Let $f$ be a function defined by: 
>   $$ f(x)=|x|^{\dfrac{1}{x-1}} $$
>   Then :
>
> Choose the correct option. more than one may be correct
>
> 1. the domain of $f$ is  $D_{f}=\mathbb{R}\backslash \{1\}$
> 2. $f$ can be extended by continuity to $1$ with $f(1)=\dfrac{1}{e}$
> 3. $f$ can be extended by continuity to $1$ and extended function is differentiable at $1$ And the derivative is $-\dfrac{e}{2}$
> 4. $f$ is differentiable on its domain, and $f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{(x-1)^{2}}|x|^{\dfrac{1}{x-1}-1}$

My thoughts

1. False because 
   $D_{f}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid \ f(x)\in \mathbb{R} \}$ then : 
   $x\in D_{f} \iff f(x)\in\mathbb{R} \iff x-1\neq 0  \text{ and } x\neq 0 \iff x\neq 1 \text{ and } x\neq 0  \iff D_{f}=\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0,1\}$
2. False because
   when $x$ goes to $1$ then $|x|=x$
   $ \lim_{x\to 1}f(x)= \lim_{x\to 1}|x|^{\dfrac{1}{x-1}}=\lim_{x\to 1}e^{\dfrac{1}{x-1} \ln(x)}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\dfrac{1}{x-1} \ln(x)}=e^{1}$ since $x\mapsto e^x$ is continous and  $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\dfrac{1}{x-1} \ln(x)=1$ then $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=e\neq \dfrac{1}{e}$
3. true because we looking to calculate $f'(1)$
   when $x$ goes to $1$, $|x|=x$ then
   $ f(x)=x^{\dfrac{1}{x-1}}=e^{\dfrac{1}{x-1}\ln(x)}$ then 
   $ f'(x)=\left(e^{\dfrac{1}{x-1} \ln(x)}\right)'=
   \left(\dfrac{ \dfrac{1}{x}(x-1)-\ln(x)}{(x-1)^{2}}\right)e^{\dfrac{1}{x-1} \ln(x) }
   =\left(\dfrac{ \dfrac{x-1-x\ln(x)}{x} }{(x-1)^{2}}\right)e^{\dfrac{1}{x-1} \ln(x) }=\left( \dfrac{x-1-x\ln(x) }{x(x-1)^{2}}\right)e^{\dfrac{1}{x-1} \ln(x) }  $

then $\lim_{x\to 1 } f'(1)$

by applying hopital's rule twice we get

$$\lim _{x\to \:1}\left(\frac{x\left(1-\ln \left(x\right)\right)-1}{x\left(x-1\right)^2}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}=\lim _{x\to \:1}\left(\frac{-\ln \left(x\right)}{\left(x-1\right)\left(3x-1\right)}\right)=\lim _{x\to \:1}\left(\frac{-\frac{1}{x}}{6x-4}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}$$ on the other hand $f(1)=e$ finaly $$f'(1)=-\dfrac{e}{2}$$
 4. False
 since $ f'(x)=\left( \dfrac{x-1-x\ln(x) }{x(x-1)^{2}}\right)e^{\dfrac{1}{x-1} \ln(x) }  \neq \dfrac{1}{(x-1)^{2}}|x|^{\dfrac{1}{x-1}-1}$

From Wolframe i got :

[image]

- **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: is my proof correct

Comment: The first two look fine. The third point seems incomplete to me. The fourth could be made a bit cleaner. Notice that for $x>0$, $f(x)=|x|^{1/(x-1)}=x^{1/(x-1)}$.

Comment: why do you say that (2) is false and then proceed to prove that it is true?  Also the calculations are easier on log f(x) than with f(x) and you can make use of the power series for log(1+x).

Comment: 2 is totaly false i prove that $f(1)=e$ not $\dfrac{1}{e}$ as the statement said by the way could you suggest ur answer with power series fo $log(1+x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the domain, you have to recognize that if $x = 0$, then you would have $|0|^{1/(0-1)} = 0^{-1} = 1/0$, which is clearly not well-defined.

If we take the limit as $x \to 1$, in this neighborhood, $|x| = x$, hence we find $$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \exp \left( \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\log x}{x-1} \right) = \exp\left( \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\log x - \log 1}{x - 1} \right)$$ from which we conclude that the inner limit is simply the derivative of $g(x) = \log x$ at $x = 1$, thus the value of $f(x)$ that would make $f$ continuous at $x = 1$ is $e^1 = e$.

For (3), observe as in (2) that in the neighborhood of $x = 1$, $|x| = x$ and it suffices to consider $$h(x) = x^{1/(x-1)},$$ and logarithmic differentiation gives $$h'(x) = h(x) \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{\log x}{x-1}\right] = x^{1/(x-1)} \left( \frac{x(1-\log x) - 1}{x(x-1)^2} \right).$$  If we "fill in" the point of discontinuity at $x = 1$ by defining $h(1) = e$, then we must consider the limit of the other factor.  We can evaluate this by a number of methods, but L'Hoptial's rule makes quick work of it.  The result is $-1/2$ for the factor in parentheses, hence $h$ has a derivative of $-e/2$ at $x = 1$.

So for at least the first three parts, the answers should be:  (1) False, (2) False, (3) True.

Comment: As for the fourth, OP is missing a factor of $\log x$ in one of the terms, but the conclusion is correct.

Comment: @heropup thank u but  i still can't see what i sould show to proof the statement  c is true

Comment: should i proof that $$f'(1)=-\dfrac{e}{2}$$

Comment: @Educ for $f(x)$ to be differentiable at $x=1$, you have to establish that $f'(x)$ is continuous $x=1$. This would entail showing that $\lim\limits_{x\to1}f'(x)=-\frac{e}{2}$.

Comment: @user170231 thank u that's what i did but for 2 it's false just check it again

Comment: @Educ for the second part, you computed $\lim\limits_{x\to1}{\bf f(x)}$, not $\lim\limits_{x\to1}{\bf f'(x)}$.

Comment: @user170231 the statement b said that $f(1)=\frac{1}{e}$ that's why  calculated $\lim\limits_{x\to1}{\bf f(x)}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29291/discussion-between-user170231-and-educ).